# from api.microsofttranslator.com to azure cognitive service Translator Text API on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, azure, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am using the cocorico CMS github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico

And all the translation are setup to use the old microsofttranslator.com API ;

I know I should change the URL in parameter.yml but I haven't found the replacement for api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray

I put: (all with https in front)

- cocorico.translator.translate.url:
  api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray
- cocorico.translator.scope.url:
  api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/
  (was    api.microsofttranslator.com )
- cocorico.translator.token.url:
  api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken
  ( datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13/)
- cocorico.translator.grant.type: 'client_credentials'

There is also cocorico.translator.secret.key: parameter but in the Azure portal there are 2 different keys but no secret key so shall I put the 2nd key as the secret key?

Is this correct?

Is there a link to replace http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray with ?

And is there anything else to replace in Symfony to make it work ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to change the HTTP TranslateMenthod URL: `http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/TranslateArray`.
- You can either use **KEY 1** or **KEY 2** as `cocorico.translator.secret.key`.

Check out [PHP code sample with TranslateArrayMethod](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/HTTP-Code-Samples/blob/c68127f87c2bd9e5a199c042620d9bd43ceb937e/PHP/TranslateArrayMethod.php).

Answer (score 0):

Cocolabs have just published their new translation solution based on the new Azur version of microsoft.

You can see here the commit: https://github.com/Cocolabs-SAS/cocorico/commit/39960f0677870cb8212ff3b8e47819837a2b88f2